# Which is the right exponent $\alpha>0$ which makes this inequality true?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions

Let $\varepsilon>0$ and $f, g:\mathbb{R}^*\to\mathbb{R}$ are both functions which behaves like $-1/|x|^{\alpha}$ with $\alpha>0$ for $|x|\le\varepsilon$.

Assume that
$$f(x)\le -\frac{1}{|x|} \text{ for } |x|\le\varepsilon.$$

My question is: which is the right exponent $\alpha>0$ which makes the inequality
$$f(x) + |g(x)|\le -\frac{1}{|x|} \text{ for } |x|\le\varepsilon$$
remain true?

I tried with an example. I took $f(x)=-\frac{1}{|x|^2}$ and then $g(x) = -\frac{1}{|x|^\alpha}$ with $\alpha\in (0, 2)$ make it works.

But how to have derive a "general" relation which does not depend on the choice of the exponent of $f$?

Thank you.

Comment: @AnneBauval, thank you for your comment. But at least we can say that if $f(x)=1/|x|^{\beta}$ with $\beta >1$, hence we can take $g(x) =-1/|x|^\alpha$ with $\alpha\in (0, \beta)$ to make the inequality works?

Comment: Then please edit your post to reformulate your question (including: to make which inequality work?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $\alpha,\beta,\gamma\in\Bbb R,$ we have $$-\frac1{|x|^\beta}+\frac1{|x|^\alpha}\le-\frac1{|x|^\gamma}$$
for $|x|$ sufficiently small iff
$$\alpha,\gamma<\beta.$$